# Mysql in bash script

Tags: bash, mysql

Hi Im running the following mysql query using a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -f        # disable globbing
IFS=$'\n'     # set field separator to NL (only)

arr=($(sudo mysql -u root -h localhost  -e "USE mydb;SELECT * FROM sites" | awk 'NR>1'))

echo $arr
```

which is returning the following:

```
1       Jhon     Richards     jhonrichards@gmail.com
```

Then I'm trying to get just the firstname (Jhon) and store in a variable, I'm adding this line:

```
firstname=$arr | awk '{print $2}'
```

However I'm doing something wrong because then I'm trying to print the result with the following line:

```
echo $firstname
```

Which is not printing anything. What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Silly question, but why not write a better SQL query? If all you need is the vale of `firstname`, then `SELECT firstname FROM sites` would supply this 

Comment: what if you just do "echo ${arr[1]}" ?

Comment: Your firstname command is wrong.  You would need to have it as an echo instead just like you have in your `echo $firstname` command.  It should be `firstname=$(echo $arr | awk '{print $2}')`

Comment: matigo: I cant to do that because I need the other columns to be stored in variables as well.   jpbrain: I not getting what I need. Terrance: You gave the right answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
firstname=$arr | awk '{print $2}'
```

is actually trying to set `firstname` to the command of what `$arr` is set for so it should error out with `command not found`.

If you `echo $arr` as a complete command then you can grab the positional parameter as needed.

```
firstname=$(echo $arr | awk '{print $2}')
```

There also are other ways to get positional parameters.  Feel free to look them up.